# Is there a way to create an unspecified number of nested resources in a ROR form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have a form to create a workout routine, and it can also create exercises as a nested attribute of a workout routine. I have it set to create 10 exercises. However, if the user does not fill out all 10 fields, it will create blank data for the remaining exercises. Is there a way for a ROR form to create any number of nested resources without creating any blank data? Please note that the solution must use only ruby/rails no javascript. Here is the code from the form:

```
<%= f.label :exercise %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :exercise_ids, Exercise.all, :id, :name %>
<%= f.fields_for :exercises, workout_routine.exercises do |exercises_form| %>
  <li>
    <%= exercises_form.label :name %>
    <%= exercises_form.text_field :name %>

    <%= exercises_form.label :sets %>
    <%= exercises_form.text_field :sets %>

    <%= exercises_form.label :reps %>
    <%= exercises_form.text_field :reps %>

    <%= exercises_form.label :target %>
    <%= exercises_form.text_field :target %>
  </li> 
<% end %>
```

and here is the code from the controller action:

```
def new
  @workout_routine = WorkoutRoutine.new 
  @workout_routine.exercises.build 
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
  @workout_routine.exercises.build
end




def create
  @workout_routine = WorkoutRoutine.create(workout_routine_params)
  if @workout_routine.save
    redirect_to workout_routine_path(@workout_routine)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Workout Routine cannot have the same name as an existing routine"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Here is the custom writer method for adding nested attributes, located in workout_routine.rb:

```
def exercises_attributes=(exercise_attributes)
  exercise_attributes.values.each do |exercise_attribute|
    exercise = Exercise.find_or_create_by(exercise_attribute)
    self.exercises << exercise
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you checked gem `cocoon`? https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: I know, you don't want to use javascript as well as accepts_nested_attributes_for. Why to generate object 10 times while you can build it dynamically. You can control it too. Do check the cocoon gem([https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon]) as also mentioned by @Emu.

Comment: Your approach seems inherently flawed. You are building 10 blank exercises on the workout_routine record before getting to your form, and then you are creating 10 new exercises on the same workout_routine record in your create action. You should choose to do one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do this using only Rails. In your WorkoutRoutine model, you need to reject exercises that are blank, like this:

```
# models/workout_routine.rb

class WorkoutRoutine < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :exercises
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises, reject_if: lambda { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }
end
```

Also, you can replace the 10 lines of identical code in your #new action with:

```
10.times { @workout_routine.exercises.build }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. However, one specification of the project was that I do not use accepts_nested_attributes_for, but instead use a custom writer. How would that code look if I instead have a custom writer like this:

Comment: def exercises_attributes=(exercise_attributes)
    exercise_attributes.values.each do |exercise_attribute|
      exercise = Exercise.find_or_create_by(exercise_attribute)
      self.exercises << exercise
    end
  end

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code for the custom writer, and indicate in what file it lives.